# AngularJS nested $state issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
  $stateProvider.state('brands', {
    url: '/brands',
    controller: 'brandsController',
    templateUrl: 'views/brands/brands.html'
  });
```

and

```
  $stateProvider.state('brands.details', {
    url: '/details/:uid',
    controller: 'brandController',
    templateUrl: 'views/brand/brand.html',
    params: { brand: null, product: null }
  });
```

using

```
  <a ui-sref="brands.details({ uid: brand.uid, brand: brand, product: product })">{{ product.name }}</a>
```

Always redirects to the parent. Why?

Comment: can you reproduce this in a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: You probably don't have a `ui-view` container in the parent view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work fine. Just configure your `states` in the `config` part of your application once and for all. Please check this [running plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ja1ehvnfAdXdhJtvdHgt?p=preview) and compare it with your solution. Ensure you have an `<div ui-view=""></div>` inside your parent view.

#### Index view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="myApp">
  <h2>AngularJS Ui router - Demonstration</h2>
  <div data-ui-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Brands view

```
<h1>Brands</h1>
<div>
     <div>
         <span ui-sref="brands.details({uid: brand.uid, brand: brand, product: product})">
             <a href="">Brand</a>
         </span>
     </div>
     <div>
         <div ui-view=""></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/brands");

    $stateProvider
        .state("brands", {
            url: "/brands",
            controller: 'brandsController',
            templateUrl: "brands.html"
        }).state('brands.details', {
            url: '/details/:uid',
            controller: 'brandController',
            templateUrl: 'brand.html',
            params: { brand: null, product: null }
        });
}); 

myApp.controller('brandsController', function () {

});

myApp.controller('brandController', function () {

});
```

Comment: Good answer. I'll also reference to [this link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) so the OP can create dedicated views for each state